# Disable all admin UI access to authors (except to custom post type add, edit and modify)

Tags: user-access

I just created a custom post type named Catalog. Where authors can create as many entries they need. But I need to restrict/deny access to all admin parts: Posts, Profile, Media or other admin parts except their Catalog entries.

Do I need to compare against $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] or theres a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be a class from MikeSchnikel, that's already a core proposal, around the web that unsets (not only display: none;) all not needed menu items (and pages). Alternative approach, but not bad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more difficult than it needs to be it seems.

To code it without using a plugin I would suggest using `global $menu` and `global $submenu` as an array and unset them based on user role or user name. It might get more difficult if you want to define user role permissions outside default values.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

You can find the values in wp-admin/menu.php , you must look in here.
Or browse them here http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.1/wp-admin/menu.php

For example if you want to unset a menu in a function it would be something along the lines of:

```
function remove_menu() {
global $menu;
//remove post top level menu for editor role
if current_user_can('editor'){
unset($menu[5]); }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_menu');
// ($menu[5]) is the "Posts" menu
```

You can see a much more detailed example here http://hungred.com/how-to/remove-wordpress-admin-menu-affecting-wordpress-core-system/